# Get multiple textbox values from asp.net ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I'm very new to C# and  asp.net

After struggling with it for hours, I've been able to populate a listview from a table in my database, which is awesome. The problem comes when I try to update an item.

Right now my function for updating is:

```
public static void UpdateBook(USER_BOOK book)
{

    var result = from r in ctx.USER_BOOK
                 where r.user_username == book.user_username &&
                 r.title == book.title
                 select r;

    result.FirstOrDefault().title = book.title;
    result.FirstOrDefault().author = book.author;
    result.FirstOrDefault().numpages = book.numpages;
    ctx.SaveChanges();

}
```

The problem there is clearly that since the book I'm passing in is the updated one, if the title is changed, there's a problem (whether from editing the wrong book, or not finding a book to edit)

The solution which occurs to me seems to be to capture the initial values when the user clicks the edit button, store them in the session, and the retrieve them from within my function.

I've gotten as far as capturing the click event for the edit button, but I don't know how to retrieve the textbox contents.

Thanks in advance if you can help me.

[image: A picture of my ListView]

Comment: you should have some sort of unique primary key on your tables, that'll prevent this issue

Comment: What would you suggest? I want rows to be unique by username and title. So that each user can only store one book with a specific title. This seemed like the best way to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

Use session in this case not good. You look [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listviewupdateeventargs.keys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Try use your primary key to your code, datakey is field  primary key in database. you look function 
   `void UnitMeasureListView_ItemUpdating(Object sender, ListViewUpdateEventArgs e)`
in link.You can acess e.NewValues, e.Keys to call your update function.

Comment: I apologize, but how might I do this? I read the documentation, and even tried some code. But it does not seem to work correctly. e.Keys does not even seem to be accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add GUID to book table.it will be primary key of your Book table.All the transaction can be done based on This GUID try with this .make sure Always keep your session id associate with this GUID

```
    var result = from r in ctx.USER_BOOK
                 where r.user_username == book.user_username &&
                 r.Guid == Session['bookGuid']
                 select r;
```